# HTML5 file browse tag

Tags: jquery, html

I am using Html5 in Firefox 8 for my web page. I am using the jquery File style plugin to replace the boring Browse button with an image. I want to display details of the files selected using the control. Using the files[] array I can get the size, type and name but not the last modification date and time.

Is there any way of getting this information.

```
<input class="browseFile" type="file" multiple="multiple" required="required" autofocus="autofocus" onchange="selectFiles(this)" />
function selectFiles(object)
 {
  var filename="";
  for(var i = 0;i < object.files.length; i++)
      {
      filename = object.files[i].name;
      $("<div style='border: 1px solid'><p>"+filename+"</p></div>").appendTo(".rightDiv");
      //$(".browseFile").attr('value',filename);
      }
  $(".browseFile").attr('value',filename);
 }
```

Please help me with this...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `lastModifiedDate` property:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $(".browseFile").change(function(e) {
        var filename = "";
        for(var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
            filename = this.files[i].name;
            lastMod = this.files[i].lastModifiedDate;
            $(".rightDiv").append("<div style='border: 1px solid'><p>" + filename + "(" + lastMod + ")</p></div>");
        }
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wCPyw/1/).

Updated the above to give a slightly better date output:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $(".browseFile").change(function(e) {
        var filename = "";
        for(var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
            filename = this.files[i].name;
            lastMod = new Date(this.files[i].lastModifiedDate);
            dd = lastMod.getDate();
            mm = lastMod.getMonth() + 1;
            yyyy = lastMod.getFullYear();
            lastModString = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;
            $(".rightDiv").append("<div style='border: 1px solid'><p>" + filename + "(" + lastModString + ")</p></div>");
        }
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wCPyw/2/).

Comment: Searched on the net and found that lastModifiedDate property is not implemented for firefox 8! Any other work around??

Answer (score 0):

I modified it: http://jsfiddle.net/wCPyw/